# Using Siesta with XML

Tags: siesta-swift

I'm having trouble figuring out how to read XML content using Siesta. I've tried stuff like this (in my Service subclass):

```
configureTransformer("*") { (content: NSData, entity) -> NSXMLDocument? in
  return try? NSXMLDocument(data: content, options: 0)
}
```

..but it doesn't seem to get called. Am I on the right track at all?

**Update:** Here's the Siesta log for a single resource:

```
[Siesta:Configuration] Computing configuration for GET Siesta.Resource(https://[host]/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/running:any,branch:develop)[]
[Siesta:Configuration] Applying config 0 [Siesta default response parsers] to Siesta.Resource(https://[host]/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/running:any,branch:develop)[]
[Siesta:Configuration] Applying config 1 [custom] to Siesta.Resource(https://[host]/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/running:any,branch:develop)[]
[Siesta:Staleness] Siesta.Resource(https://[host]/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/running:any,branch:develop)[] is not up to date: no error | no data
[Siesta:Network] GET https://[host]/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/running:any,branch:develop
[Siesta:Observers] Siesta.Resource(https://[host]/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/running:any,branch:develop)[L] sending Requested to 1 observer
[Siesta:Observers] Siesta.Resource(https://[host]/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/running:any,branch:develop)[L] sending Requested to <XTSideBarDataSource: 0x600000091440>
[Siesta:Network] 200 ← GET https://[host]/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/running:any,branch:develop
[Siesta:StateChanges] Siesta.Resource(https://[host]/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/running:any,branch:develop)[] received new data from Network : Entity(content: <OS_dispatch_data: data[0x61000026a4c0] = { leaf, size = 3201, buf = 0x1021f2200 }>, charset: nil, headers: ["cache-control": "no-cache, no-store", "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains", "content-length": "3201", "content-type": "application/xml", "set-co…
[Siesta:Observers] Siesta.Resource(https://[host]/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/running:any,branch:develop)[D] sending NewData(Network) to 1 observer
[Siesta:Observers] Siesta.Resource(https://[host]/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/running:any,branch:develop)[D] sending NewData(Network) to <XTSideBarDataSource: 0x600000091440>
```

Comment: This is on OS X, I take it?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: There are no response transformers showing up in the log at all, which is curious. May be OS X…er, macOS related. Will investigate locally.

Comment: Well, I found some shortcomings in Siesta’s pipeline logging, but couldn’t reproduce your issue. This works for me: https://gist.github.com/pcantrell/771ebb53e6acf02ed091c5d29a1ca941

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you’re on the right track. `"*"` only matches a single path segment; try `"**"` instead.

Comment: That didn't do it. I set a breakpoint, added an NSLog call, it's not happening.

Comment: In that case, try `Siesta.enabledLogCategories = LogCategory.detailed` and update your question with the output (omitting any sensitive info, of course). That should help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Updated with the log.

Comment: In another part of my app I tried accessing a different XML resource on the same server and it worked fine, so I'll just have to figure out what I did wrong the first time through. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, file bugs if you find any!